# Understanding algebraic actions and Chevalley's theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

According to (a special case of) Chevalley's theorem: Let $G$ be a closed algebraic subgroup  of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ and $H$ a closed subgroup of $G$, then there exists a line (through the origin) $L\subset \mathbb C^n$ such that $H=\{g\in G; \ g\cdot L=L\}$.

Now consider  a compact variety $X$ such that $G/H\hookrightarrow X$ be  equivariantly embedded. hence we have the situation $G/H=G\cdot x\overset{ open}{\hookrightarrow}\overline{G\cdot x}\overset{ closed }{\hookrightarrow}X$. So if $Gx$ is a mininmal dimension orbit then it is compact? Is my assertion correct?

Comment: This is true if $X$ is compact. Else you can take a non-compact $G$ acting on itself by translation.

Comment: So I wanna understand this, if $G/H$ is equivariantly embedded in a compact variety $X$, then any algebraic subgroup of $G$ has a compact orbit in $X$?

Comment: I don't think so, because a priori a subgroup $H' \subset G$ acts only on $G/H$ which might be non compact. If you know that $G/H$ is compact then this is true.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something here: So in my comment above, $G$ acts on $X$ (is that true?) then by Chevalley: $G/H=G\cdot x\subset  X$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Could you make an edit with the hypothesis and the question ?

Comment: @ Nicolas Hemelsoet I did

Comment: Thank you for the edit. The answer is yes. Since $G$ acts on $G/H$ it also acts on the closure. And a minimal dimension orbit in a closed variety is compact.

Comment: Sorry, Is it a standard fact from topology that if $A$ is closed in the subset $B$ then $A$ is also closed in $\overline B$?

Comment: Yes that's true. Because if $B - A$ is open then $\overline{B} - A = (\overline{B} - B) \cup (B - A)$ is also open.

Comment: $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ is closed in $(0,1)$, but it is not closed in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @D_S : too late for me to do math ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming beforehand that $X$ is a compact variety on which $G$ acts, in which $G/H$ embeds equivariantly onto an orbit of minimal dimension in $X$?  Then yes, your claim follows because orbits of minimal dimension are closed, and a closed subset of a compact variety is compact.

By the way, I don't think you have stated Chevalley's theorem correctly.  Rather, *given* $H$ as a closed subgroup of a linear algebraic group $G$, there *exists* an embedding of $G$ into some $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ and a line $L \subset \mathbb C^n$ such that $H = \{g \in G: g.L = L\}$

Comment: Does equivariantly embedding in $X$ imply an action on $X$?

Comment: Yes.  A $G$-equivariant map is a morphism in the category of $G$-varieties.

Comment: Thanks. But I was wondering actually is it necessary to assume equivariant  embedding.. I mean, if $Y\subset X$ with $X$ compact and $G$ acts on $Y$, then the closure of any orbit is compact and hence the minimal orbits are compact!

Comment: I don't think that works.  Think about what you are saying when you talk about a minimal orbit in $X$ (or say the closure of $Y$), if you are not assuming that $G$ acts on $X$ or $\overline{Y}$.

Comment: Where is the problem?